# Nexus 7 developer build

Tags: android

I've been fighting Nexus Root Toolkit for a while and decided I must be missing something obvious. I have a Nexus 7 2013 edition. I flashed it 6 mos ago and the result was a fully-rooted device that, when I opened an adb shell, the shell opened as root. I recently flashed it up to Marshmallow and I no longer have root when the shell opens. For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get that back.

When I do adb root, I get a warning that adbd cannot run as root in production builds, so clearly I have a production build and need to change it, but I'm not sure how or to what.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out - took a while to remember. NRT comes with a "modified boot.img" which can be used, according to the tool, to "temporarily boot a modified boot.img to enable running privileged commands". Last time around, I replaced the boot image with this temporary image.

I'd do that now, but the current modified boot image never fully boots. I get full device access via adb (including shell which defaults to root), but the OS won't fully load.

I will update this answer when a new boot image is released which actually works. Meanwhile, it'll be tedious but I'll just keep putting it into 'temp boot image" mode when I need this access.